# How to include first/last dates in matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a time series plot I am drawing using matplotlib in a jupyter notebook.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P
from datetime import date
```

First, I create the initial plot and describe x and y:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=200)

dates = ['2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12', '2018-01',
       '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-06', '2018-07',
       '2018-08', '2018-09', '2018-10', '2018-11', '2018-12', '2019-01',
       '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07']

y = [2002, 2630, 2032, 1816, 1867, 2282, 2064, 2316, 2391, 2134, 1833, 1982, 2053, 1836, 2107, 1891, 1729, 1794, 1908, 2267, 2194, 2248, 2216, 2408,]

# Convert to ordinal dates here so that computation of x degree polynomial is easier
x = list(map(lambda x: date.fromisoformat(f'{x}-01').toordinal(), dates))
```

Second, I add two lines to the plot (line & poly fit):

```py
# plot the line
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'k', linewidth=3, label='Awesome SO answers')

# create 2nd degree Polynomial series instance
c1 = P.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 2)

# Returns the x, y values at n linearly spaced points across the domain.
x1, y1 = c1.linspace(n=len(x))

poly2, = ax.plot(x1, y1, 'r', linewidth=3, label='2nd deg poly fit')

# create labels and call set_xticklabels
# I think this is were the problem is. 
# How do I set the x ticks to include the first/last date?
new_labels = [date.fromordinal(int(xt)) for xt in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)

# make plot look nicer, add legend
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=8)
first_legend = ax.legend(handles=[line, poly2], loc='best')
```

See the below output seems to **hide the first/last dates**. Notice the last datapoint on x in the output is '2019-05' but it is really '2019-07'. It is **preferred to include the last date** so that it is clear the data are current. There must be some rules matplotlib is using to calculate the xticks. How do I get the xticks to respect the first/last dates?

[image: Plotting some fake data]

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. First create evenly spaced array over a specified interval with `np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=6)` then call `ax.set_xticks()` with the output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I checked the value of `ax.get_xticks()` I noticed that the min/max values of `x` were **not included**. So it is no wonder they were not showing up. To get this working I just had to recreate an array of ordinals that include the min/max values of `x` using `np.linspace`.

To see what `xticks` was previously set at, we can run:

```py
print(ax.get_xticks()) # [736500. 736600. 736700. 736800. 736900. 737000. 737100. 737200. 737300.]
```

#### We can verify that the min/max values were not included:

```py
print(f'min: {min(x)} max: {max(x)}') # min: 736542 max: 737241
```

#### What we would like is an evenly spaced array over a specified interval beginning at the min(x) and ending at max(x):

```py
# create new array of ordinals
x_ticks = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=6) # [736542.  736681.8 736821.6 736961.4 737101.2 737241. ]

# Now set the xticks so that the new_labels array will be computed with the correct values
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)

# create new labels
new_labels = [date.fromordinal(int(xt)).strftime("%b %Y") for xt in ax.get_xticks()]
# ['Aug 2017', 'Dec 2017', 'May 2018', 'Sep 2018', 'Feb 2019', 'Jul 2019']

# set the labels
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

[image: plot polynomials with matplotlib]

Comment: Except that now the ticks can be off by as much as a (little less than) month. I.e. Aug 2017 may be ticked at the first of august, Jul 2019 may be the 30th of july.